# mobx-react How to observe specific object inside observable array in mobx-react

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Let's say we have one textbox in each cell with 5 rows and 10 columns.

That is, there are 50 textboxes.

And in the mobx Store class

```
@observable
data = [
  {
     rowIndex:0,
     colIndex :0,
     value : 1,
   },
  {
     rowIndex:0,
     colIndex: 1,
     value:1
  }
//Obviously, there will be 48 more properties.
]
```

That is, while the data variable is observable, it represents values ​​according to the cell index.

Then, how can each textbox component be re-rendered only when the value corresponding to rowIndex and colIndex is changed?

For reference, the textbox component must use a functional component here.

I would be grateful if you could explain the sudo code or mobx concept and syntax that can solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Maybe you could make a minimal reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/? It's not quite clear what you want, because so far it seems like a basic observer component for each cell, not clear why it might not be enough for your case?

Comment: @Danila i already tried. But, My problem is that 50 textboxes are rendered when changed value inside observable array in mobx. Becuase one TextBox Component reused.  I dynamically get textbox 50 times. It's my answer. Please, So. not coding, let me know concept or syntax which i can solve.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mobx doc](https://mobx.js.org/react-optimizations.html#dereference-values-late), you should dereference values as late as possible.

Below is sort of your initial example. Clicking "value" rerenders only corresponding cell.

```js
// mobx v6.7.0
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'

const tableData = observable([
    {
        rowIndex: 0,
        colIndex: 0,
        value: 1,
    },
    {
        rowIndex: 0,
        colIndex: 1,
        value: 1
    },
    {
        rowIndex: 0,
        colIndex: 2,
        value: 1
    }
])

const Cell = observer(({ data }) => {
    const { rowIndex, colIndex, value } = data
    console.log('render');

    return  <div>
                <div>row {rowIndex}; col: {colIndex}</div>
                <div onClick={action(() => data.value += 1)}>value: {value}</div>
                -----
            </div>
})

function AppTest() {
    return (
        <>
            {tableData.map((d, i) => <Cell data={d} key={i} />)}
        </>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppTest />, document.body)
```

Initial rendering logs 3 times, any of individual cell update updates only corresponding cell.

Some notes:

1. `<Cell>` is wrapped with [`observer` HOC](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#react-integration) from `mobx-react-lite` package - that is how you integrate mobx and react
2. Cell's `onClick` handler is wrapped with `action` function - state updates in mobx must run in transactions and [as far outward as possible](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#wrapping-functions-using-action).